# How to record multiple Barcode Scans into my Excel File datasource in Powerapps?

Tags: excel, qr-code, barcode-scanner, powerapps

I'm a newbie on PowerApps so I apologize if I'm doing something wrong.

I'm working on an inventory app where users scan a QR code and the value of that QR code gets recorded into my datasource. So far, this works when scanning one QR code at a time. However, what I want is to scan multiple QR codes in one go and tell my app to record the values of the different QR codes to different rows.

This is what my Barcode Reader OnScan code looks like:

```
Patch(
    inventoryList,
    Defaults(inventoryList),
    {
        'ITEM CODE': First(BarcodeReader1.Barcodes).Value,
        ITEM: LookUp(lookUpTable, CODE = First(BarcodeReader1.Barcodes).Value, NAME)
    }
)
```

This bit of code makes it so that the value of the QR Code gets written to the column 'ITEM CODE', and the app then looks up a lookUpTable for the name of that item code. The end result will be the app displaying both the item name and item code in a Gallery. This works fine but only for single scanning. When I try multiple scans through ScanningMode(ScanMultiple), only the first QR code gets read and the rest are... I don't really know what happens to them.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.